# Delete an element of a combox in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following function in Javascript:

```
function handleSelectClick(whattodo) {
    var selectObj, selectedValue, select, option;
    selectObj = document.forms[0].functionselect;
    selectedValue = selectObj.options[selectObj.selectedIndex].text;
    select = document.getElementById("second");
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = option.text = selectedValue;
    if (whattodo == 1) {
        select.add(option);
    } else {
        select.remove(option);
    }
}
```

which handles any click I do in the following form:

```
<form>
    <select onclick="handleSelectClick(1);" name="functionselect" size="20" style="font-size:10pt;width:34ex;">
        <option value="">abs</option>
        <option value="">acos</option>
        <option value="">acosh</option>
    </select>
    <select id="second" onclick="handleSelectClick(2);" name="functionselect2" size="20" style="font-size:10pt;width:34ex;"></select>
    <br><input onclick="handleKeyUp(9999999);" value="Reset list" type="button">
</form>
```

I want to delete the element of the select with `id="second"`. This indeed deletes one element, but the first one in the box and not the one I click. How can I address this problem?

Comment: try this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/add-and-remove-listbox-items-in-javascript/

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the selected element not the created element.

Demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phLkzprm/)

```
function handleSelectClick(whattodo) {
var selectObj, selectedValue, select;
selectObj = document.forms[0].functionselect;
selectedValue = selectObj.options[selectObj.selectedIndex].text;
select = document.getElementById("second");
if (whattodo == 1) {
    var option;
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = option.text = selectedValue;
    select.add(option);
} else {
    select.remove(select.options[select.selectedIndex]);
}
}
```